# How can invalidate the authenticity token for a signup form after the first POST request is received in rails applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authenticity-token

My application will create a batch of new accounts on a Pitchfork attack. My application provides a authenticity token when the signup form is viewed. I want to invalidate this token once the first PUT request containing this token arrives, so that no other user accounts can be created using the same token. In other words, every time an account should be created, the signup form should be viewed first.

Comment: What is a pitchfork attack?

Comment: multiple payload(parameters) sets

Comment: If you are talking about the Rails CSRF token you invalidate it by resetting or nulling the session. But it sounds more like what you want is a custom store of authentication tokens either in the database or memory based storage.

Comment: Note that the Rails CSRF token is only really intended to counter CSRF. It does not actually protect against double submissions.